# How can I get all the documents in a collection that has a field with same value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The collection has ~400k documents and I can't seem to find a way to achieve this. Any MongoDB wizard out there who could help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "has a field with the same value"?  ... a field with a specified value? ... groups of documents that all share the same value for a field?  Some example documents with desired output would help explain what you want to do.  Showing some code with your attempts and explaining what doesn't work would also help.

Comment: I could be a bit more specific. So what do I mean by "has a field with the same value" For example 2 or more documents have the field "url" : "www.google.com". I want to get out all the documents that have duplicate values. I don't have any snippets or not looking for some solution written for me, just for a direction where should I look to get this done.

Comment: You could `"$group"` documents with an `"_id"` of the field where you want to find duplicates and then filter the `"$group"` results where there is more than one document.